# How to find rational roots of a polynomial in 5 variables in a cube

Tags: equation-solving, findinstance

I am trying to find  rational numbers $m,k,l,o,z,R$ such that

`R^12 - (k l^2 m - l m^2 o - k^2 l z + l o z) R^6 + o^3*z^3 == 0`

in the following cube:

```
 Abs[m - 36644/105961] < 10^-5 &&
 Abs[l + 1232/293] < 10^-5 && 
 Abs[k - 249130793119621/28710473614615] < 10^-5 && 
 Abs[o - 158713667/29789603] < 10^-5 && 
 Abs[z - 209714811/21722005] < 10^-5
```

($R$ can be anything)

I tried `FindInstance` and `NSolve` but after a few hours I gave up as it was coming up with nothing. I do believe that it is possible no such numbers exist but I figured I would ask if there is other way looking for rational roots. However, I am inclined to believe that a solution exists. If I fix some rationals say $o,z,l,R$, I get a quadratic polynomial in two variables with integer coefficients I can control fairly well. Which by Hasse Principle should have rational points for some of my choices.

Anyway, is there a better way to look for rational roots here?

Comment: First see if there are real roots within those constraints. If there are, then solve for `R^6` and figure out what will make the discriminant rational. There will be more after that but it might be the right approach.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I am not sure what you mean? It is easy to show there is a real root. Now the problem is to find a rational root. I can solve it for R^6 and probably make that rational since it is "removing" one square root (since its a quadratic in $R^6$). But then I need the outcome to be a rational whose 6th root is a rational. That is why I think looking for rational roots of this polynomial algorithmically (somehow) should be easier.